# Place floats on a separate page before the referring text

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I am familiar with how/why LaTeX places floats in the way it does. I have searched for questions here and have read many answers relating to "floats", "left/right pages", etc., but have not found a solution. I use the `book` class, but with the `oneside` option. I can change this to another class if it will not affect my document.

I would like to place selected floats on their own page before the text which refers to them, so that the page with the float can become a left/facing page to the text, which is the "right" page. The entire document is one-sided and will be printed one-sided. I realize that this will mean that the float/s will appear before the text referring to them -- that is exactly what I would like. More than one float may be placed on the page if necessary.

For example:

```
+----1---+
|  Some  |
|  Text  |
|        |
+--------+

+----2---+
| Float1 |
|        |
| Float2 |
+--------+

+----3---+
| See    |
| Fig 1. |
| Text   |
+--------+
```

I have not considered the `semioneside` package, as it contains many warnings and recommendations not to use it in its documentation.

Comment: Must the floats appear on the page prior to their first mention in the text? Would it be acceptable to have a float appear on the same page as its callout?

Comment: @Mico: Good point -- thanks. Yes, floats may appear on the page where they are mentioned if possible. What I want to avoid is a float appearing two or three pages away. Some portions of text refer to a few floats, so there is physically not enough space for them all to appear near to the text. Hence, placing them before the text on their own page, which will then be bound on the left, facing the text page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `placeins` package and use `\FloatBarrier` before the text that references the floats, then if there are any pending floats a `\clearpage` will be issued to generate float pages so floats never float past the marked point.